# How to traverse an Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array something like this

```
$steps = explode("[;;]",$str);
```

So the $steps holds value that I have to use to show a step/step procedure in PHP .

The array looks like this

```
$steps = array('corredores' , 'something' , 'something'...and so one );
```

I am trying to display forms according to the value saved in the array for the first step I am doing something like this

```
switch($steps[0]){
    case 'categorias' :
    include  'obj/categorias.php';
                //$step='categorias';
                break;
    case 'corredores':
    include 'obj/corredores.php';
                //$step='corredores';
                break;
    case 'monedas':
    include 'obj/monedas.php';
                //$step='monedas';
                break;
    case 'location':
    include 'obj/location.php';
                //$step='location';
                break;
    default:
    break;  
}
```

//Here I am trying to match the next value from the array that I will save in this post value on every step

```
if(isset($_POST['next']))
{
include  'obj/'.$_POST["next"].'php';
                //$step='categorias';
                break;  

}
else {


}
```

So when I click on the next button of each file it should match with the next value from the array and show the related file

The HTML content of every files has following structure

```
<form method="post" action="./index.php" name="form_name">
<table><tr><th>Some Name</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" value="next"></td></tr></table>

  <input type="hidden" name="next" value="<?php  //here i will add the value for next ?>">
</form>
```

Can any one give me some suggestion

Comment: how does your $steps variable actually looks like ?

Comment: @NitsanBaleli please check the question I have updated

Comment: the value of the hidden input should be the $steps[current+1] each time you're printing the table. Use the Key() function

Comment: @briosheje Thanks let me try I will look into the documentation

Comment: To be clearer, you want to echo something like this: `<?php echo $steps[key($steps[$_POST['next'])+1]; ?> ` The logic behind this is quite simple: getting from the POST value the index of the key which is after the next key. You need, however, to check if the key is higher than the `count($steps)`. In such a case, get the key 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per as I understand you need to search the array with POST var then echo next value in `input` tag's value attribute.

```
<?php 
 $key=0;
 if(isset($_POST['next'])){
     include  'obj/'.$_POST["next"].'php';
     $key = array_search($_POST["next"], $steps);
     if($key !== false) $key++;
     if($key==count($steps)) $key=0; 
       //if post contains last element then set $key to first OR do whatever you want
     break;  
 }
 else { }
 ?>

<input type="hidden" name="next" value="<?php echo $steps[$key]; ?>">
```